# How can I combine multiple queries in Kibana DevTools to get one result for each?

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I'm trying to write a query in Kibana DevTools that would give me one match for each query.
Let's say I've got fields (field1, field2) that I want to match with a specific value.

I want to display 1 result for each field if any logs were found for any of these fields. The code that I'm using right now that displays 1 log for 1 search is below:

(I'm looking for log that was created in the last 30 minutes and using sort to get the last one)

```
GET default*/_search
{
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
      "query_string": {
        "query": "field1:somevalue*"}
    },
    {
      "range":{"@timestamp":{"gte": "now-30m"}}
    }
  ]
}
  },
  "sort" :{
        "@timestamp":{
          "order":"desc"
        }
      }
}
```

How can I modify it to display 1 log for each field (field1, field2). Should look somehow like this:

```
GET default*/_search
{
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
      "query_string": {
        "query": "field1:somevalue*"}
    },
    {
      "range":{"@timestamp":{"gte": "now-30m"}}
    }
  ]
}
  },
  "sort" :{
        "@timestamp":{
          "order":"desc"
        }
      }
}
AND 
{
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
      "query_string": {
        "query": "field2:somevalue*"}
    },
    {
      "range":{"@timestamp":{"gte": "now-30m"}}
    }
  ]
}
  },
  "sort" :{
        "@timestamp":{
          "order":"desc"
        }
      }
}
```

The one above obviously doesn't work but wanted to visualize what I mean.
Any help appreciated

---

Val - here are some screenshots of the error I'm getting trying your solution:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LWlI.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLcua.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the [multi search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html):

```
GET default*/_msearch
{}
{"size":1,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"field1:somevalue*"}},{"range":{"@timestamp":{"gte":"now-30m"}}}]}},"sort":{"@timestamp":{"order":"desc"}}}
{}
{"size":1,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"field2:somevalue*"}},{"range":{"@timestamp":{"gte":"now-30m"}}}]}},"sort":{"@timestamp":{"order":"desc"}}}
```

In the response, you'd get exactly what you expect, i.e. the response for each query.

Comment: Thank you, but I when I'm trying your code it gives me syntax error. Seems like I cant use _msearch as this is not even available when trying with autocomplete. Could it be the version of Kibana/Elasticsearch that's causing that ?

Comment: Works well for me in Dev Tools, you need to make sure to have the whole query on a single line. Can you show a screenshot of how you're doing it?

Comment: What version of ES/Kibana are you using?

Comment: Kibana version is 5.3. I'm not sure about elasticsearch (is it the same?). I'm not sure how to check elasticsearch version ;/

Comment: Run `GET /` in Kibana

Comment: It says version number: 5.3.0 ... lucene_version: 6.4.1